# How can I create the older version of Azure Web Bot?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, version

Hi so I worked on this bot last year. I created the node js basic bot. Now I'm trying to create a new bot but it is totally different directory and files. How can I get the older version? Thanks!

Comment: Can you state why you would want to go back to the older version? It is always recommended that you follow the most up-to-date version of the bot samples so that the bot works smoothly without any issues. Older versions tend to not be compatible wit the changes made from time to time and support for resolving such issues also becomes difficult.

Comment: The new bot have different files in it. I have the older version from 2019 so I'm trying to combine them together but now everything changed. What is the best way to solve this?